# Movie where the main character is waiting all his life for a phone call

Tags: identify-this-movie

About a year ago, I happened to watch a movie in the TV while switching between channels. Those are the details I remember about it:

- It wasn't new but also not very old, probably filmed around the 90's or 00's.
- The main character was working on some secret project, don't remember details about it, something with computers and virtual reality.
- The main character was very lonely all his life, and waiting for a phone call on which he dreamed about as a youth. I think he was also deceived by his employers, letting him believe this phone call will arrive if he'll keep working for them.
- At some point he fell in love with a virtual reality female character, and found a way to enter her world in a real way. (Sounds odd, but that's what I remember.)
- The son of his boss, a teenager, helped him with his project at some point. He became sick at some point, and the boss accused the main character.

Can anyone tell what movie this is?

Comment: Don't forget to cast a vote :-) http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2250/shall-we-ban-identification-questions?cb=1

Comment: Thanks @Richard, voted. Without those, this site will lose major part of its questions and probably traffic.

Comment: @ShadowWizard But be sure to also read all the arguments presented that elaborate on how it is about much more than mere traffic (disregarding that traffic's quality) or entertainment of passerbys.

Comment: It's actually fairly new (at least newer than movies we consider "new" like Transformers or Avengers) but the cinematography is deliberately stylised which may make it look retro.

Comment: @slebetman very true, see my comment on the answer. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's a little more recent than that. This sounds like Terry Gilliam's [The Zero Theorem](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2333804/combined) from 2013.

> A hugely talented but socially isolated computer operator is tasked by Management to prove the Zero Theorem: that the universe ends as nothing, rendering life meaningless. But meaning is what he already craves.

The things you've described (the hero constantly waiting for a phone call, meeting the woman in VR, the boss's son getting sick etc.) are there. Here's the trailer:

Comment: Huh, excellent! For some reason it left an impression of old movie, and I totally forgot about the theorem. But yes, that's surely the movie. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard is it a good one?

Comment: @Adrian773 hard to say. The overall impression was "weird, but one you can't stop watching". That's why I want to watch it again. :)

Comment: @Adrian773 : It is good: not mainstream, and definitely surprising and maybe a bit difficult to grasp on the first watch (and not perfect either), but one wants to watch it again, and probably enjoys it even more then  (ad the universe makes even more sense, and little details now further enhance the overall effect of the movie) (which I think is very good).